# Buscar un registro de una columna en todas las tablas de mi base de datos en informix

Tags: sql, informix

Tengo una base de datos en la cual varias tablas tienen el campo **año de ingreso**, lo que quiero es buscar en todas las tablas que contengan el campo año de ingreso y el valor en especifico por ejemplo:

Quiero buscar en todas mis tablas que contengan la columna **año de ingreso** y que el **valor** sea *1976*, he tratado pero no encuentro algo para informix, lo mas cercano fue un query que me despliegue todas las tablas que contengas la columna año de ingreso el cual es el siguiente:

```
select t.tabname from systables t where t.tabid in ( 
select tabid from syscolumns c where c.colname = 'anioingreso')
```

Pero lo que quiero, es que me despliegue todas las tablas que cumplan con ese valor.

Les agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: No conozco informix pero si funciona como el resto de los motores tendrías que crear una sentencia SQL dinámica y ejecutarla: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=sql-execute-dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una persona externa a la página me comento que en informix no es posible lo que quiero realizar, sin embargo el siguiente query descargara en un archivo .sql TODAS las tablas con la COLUMNA anioingreso con la sintaxis del select * from y de esta forma buscara el registro en todas las tablas, se los comparto por si a alguien mas le sirve.

Créditos al Sr Aquiles Loranca.

```
UNLOAD TO "busca_registros.sql" DELIMITER ","
SELECT "SELECT * FROM "|| st.tabname || " WHERE anioingreso='1976'"
  FROM systables st, syscolumns sc
 WHERE st.tabid=sc.tabid
   AND sc.colname="anioingreso";
```